# OAUTH2.0 Automation

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, automation, postman, token

I want to automate the generation of OAUTH2.0 access_token in prescript. The script that I have written gives me a 401 response. I need to know what am I doing wrong here. 
[See The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuP1Y.png)

```js
var tokenUrl = pm.environment.get('requrl');
var clientId = pm.environment.get('clientId');
var clientSecret = pm.environment.get('secret');
var scope = pm.environment.get('scope')
var username = pm.environment.get('Username')
var password = pm.environment.get('password')

var getTokenRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: tokenUrl,
    auth: {
        type: "basic",
        basic: [
            { key: "username", value: clientId },
            { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
        ]
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'urlencoded',
        formdata: [
            { key: 'grant_type', value: 'password' },
            { key: 'username', value: username},
            { key: 'password', value: password},
            { key: 'scope', value: scope}
        ]
    }
};

pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
    var jsonResponse = response.json(),
        token = jsonResponse.access_token;
    pm.environment.set("token", token);
});
```

Comment: Does your `username` environment variable start with a lower or uppercase U? It's an Auth issue, have you tried running it with the hardcoded values to see it working before putting everything into variables.

Comment: Data is being loaded perfectly! I printed out the data and its all okay.

Comment: Given that your request is returning a 401, I would imagine that it's probably not all okay  - have you checked the Postman console to see what the exact request(Headers, body, etc) looks like? Does the response of that request show any error messages?